Magento 2 Multiple Websites or Stores
I have a current Magento 2.4 installation and I want to have another store with different categories and products but share customer information, cart, checkout and payments.  I want the user to be able to purchase something from either store at the same time, then checkout using a single cart and have the order confirmation email to go to each different store owner.
Is this possible by using either multiple websites or multiple store options?

For your requirement like

different categories and products
share customer information, cart, checkout and payments

You need to create Multi-Website System into single magento installation.

Thanks for the response.  It looks like creating separate websites (multi-site) will not allow the user to shop in both places using the same cart.  Do you have a link showing otherwise?

If user register on Globel level then, it will shop in both the website.

It seems to be a custom requirement as far as I see it.

sharing customer info can be done from the configuration (as per the answer given previously)
separating category can be done on store basis
product can be assigned on websites basis

Overall, although OOTB, there are some commonalities between your query and what Magento provides, I'd say the bottleneck will be about sharing your cart and checkout..
--> if your websites share the same domain (for instance, shoe.mydomain.com, shirt.mydomain.com), I'd look at the cookie settings and see whether this means the cart is shared or not (I have never done it and find it convoluted UX). For the checkout, I am unclear as to how you'd define the url to use?
